# What statistical test to use to compare baseline rate to changes over time?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, poisson-regression, medicine

I am working on a project for school and am having a hard time figuring out what statistical test will be conducted in order to find out if changes in the measurement rates are statistically significant or not.  The scenario I have is a hospital-sponsored health plan wants to look at the rates of emergency room visits and how many of those were the result of asthma attacks.  The hospital implemented an intervention for the insured and would like to evaluate the possibility of any improvement being the result of said intervention.

I've included the numbers I have below to get a better idea of the insured and those with asthma attacks visiting the emergency room.  If the goal is to achieve a p-value of less than 0.05 to demonstrate statistical significance, what type of test would I use?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like a contingency table (or better, could be made into one by subtracting first column from second). Then you could use the chi-square test of homogeneity. But for estimation of rates, look into Poisson rate regression. Search this site!